# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Tags: android, android-manifest

I got a crash report earlier from acra and this is the stack trace:

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.PACKAGENAME/com.PACKAGENAME.Timetable}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.PACKAGENAME.Timetable
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2093)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1204)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4801)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method._logged_invoke(Method.java:524)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:513)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.PACKAGE.Timetable
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:72)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader._logged_loadClass(ClassLoader.java:480)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:472)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1056)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
    ... 12 more
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.PACKAGE.Timetable
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:72)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader._logged_loadClass(ClassLoader.java:480)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:472)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1056)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2093)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1204)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4801)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method._logged_invoke(Method.java:524)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:513)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I think that happens because I have the following activity in the manifest, but never used.

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.PACKAGENAME.Timetable"
        android:label="@string/timetable" >
    </activity>
```

There is no class in my project called Timetable and that activity is never called. I know I should remove it then (and I will), but I'm wondering why doesn't it cause the app to crash more? That has been in the app for a few months and only caused it crash for the first time today. The app would be used quiet bit each day and I haven't been able to reproduce it (out of 100+ users it has only happened today for one user).  Why is it only happening now and am I right to assume that it's being caused by that activity?

Comment: "and that activity is never called" -- it sure looks like it is. See if there are any references to that class.

Comment: I have 3 times now and there isn't anything calling that. I am 100% sure.

Comment: @CommonsWare I can send you a copy of the code if you don't believe me.

Comment: The stack trace definitely shows the activity being started. Since you do not have an `<intent-filter>`, only your code can start it. Hence, I have no explanation of your symptoms other than your having some dusty code path that actually starts the activity, or somebody is reverse-engineering your app and tried starting it. If you are 100% certain that you are not doing that, then comment out the `<activity>` element (since it is useless) and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException means a class is missing in the application runtime. For my case, check AndroidManifest.xml first to make sure that activity is declared and then I would like to check if I have added all necessary libs to the build path.

Right click on project -> properties -> java build path -> libraries, add the libs or create one containing the classes and enable order export for the libs.